# Struts - struts-taglib.jar not found

Tags: struts2, taglib

I am new to `Struts`. I downloaded `Struts2` from its website. Now I want to refer `struts-html.tld` file in one of my `JSP` files.

But when I looked for `struts-taglib.jar` file in the downloaded struts, I didn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [the full distribution](http://apache.abdaal.com/struts/binaries/struts-2.1.8.1-all.zip) - it has everything included.

Answer (score 2):

There exists only one tag library in struts2. It is completely different compared to struts1. The tag library is struts-tags.tld which can be found in META-INF folder in struts-core-.jar.

Answer (score 2):

All the jar files in struts2 are located in:

```
..\struts-2.3.15\lib
```

However, I am not sure if there is such thing as struts-taglib.jar

You might be thinking of:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

required jar for that is: struts2-core-2.x.x.jar

Answer (score 2):

Download from the given link http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts23163 In this link go to final distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the full distribution from the struts website, and build a project out of their showcase.war if you download the latest version which is 2.5.x  or struts-blank.war if you download 2.3.x. This way you will have all the required libraries in your project. I have had all kinds of issues trying to figure out jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by downloading the `struts-taglib-1.3.5` jar separately and put it under `/WEB-INF/lib` where all my other jar files are.
After that just include the line : `<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>`
in your jsp and it should work.

Or

You could include : `<%@ taglib prefix="ss" uri="/struts-tags" %>`

Both of these methods worked for me.

Comment: FYI the first one is for struts1 and the later is for struts2.